# Loading a navigation menu, and then selecting the active class with JQuery, but it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file, header.html, with my navigation menu. I have the following code:

```
<head>
  <script> 
    $(function(){
         $("#header").load("header.html");
         console.log("loaded");
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
...
</body>
```

And then I have the following code to add the class "active" to the current tab:

```
function selectActive()
{
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     $(".inactive").each(function(){
          if($($(this).children("a")[0]).attr("href") == pgurl || $($(this).children("a")[0]).attr("href") == '' )
          {
            $(this).addClass("active");
          }
     });
};
```

I've tried to run selectActive() several ways, including $(window).load and $(window).ready and neither seems to work. There is a function call to selectActive(), but neither makes the change. (I've tried selectActive() from the console and it works as expected).

Comment: Why aren't you using document.ready?

Comment: Please clarify. Is this function part of the `header.html` or the main page? Also, where it's been called?

Answer (score 0):

So you just need that function to run on load? use `$(document).ready()` as mentioned in comments. :)

```
$(document).ready(function selectActive() {
        var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        $(".inactive").foreach(function () {
            if ($(this).children("a")[0].attr("href") === pgurl || 
                $(this).children("a")[0].attr("href") === '') 
            {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
        });    
});
```

If you have already tried this with no success, make sure you are referencing JQuery somewhere, as that is required for this to work.